# How to check if author is an administrator in discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to check if the author is an admin before he/she uses the command in the rewrite branch of discord.py

I tried:

```py
@client.command()   #Command to delete messages in bulk.
    async def clear(ctx, amount=100):
        if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator:
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount+1)
            await ctx.send(str(amount) + ' messages deleted.')
        else:
            await ctx.send('No can do mister!')
```

But this returned an error, I'm guessing because it doesn't work for the rewrite branch. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator
```

You want to use:

```
ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator
```